# Streaming printing with PHP

Tags: php, printing, streaming, echo, buffered

I've written a PHP script that makes a request to a search engine, accesses the served results, extracts some details from the results and then prints them in a more useful form.

It all works well, but something I've discovered by accident is that calling echo or print while waiting for data to be streamed in can result in the output being streamed as well. Specifically, there are multiple pages of results, so I access the first page, read in and re-print the content, then move on to the next page, and while waiting for that next page to load, the previous page's content becomes visible in the browser.

What I don't understand is why this happens so inconsistently. Sometimes exactly one page will be printed before moving onto the next page, sometimes less and sometimes more. Then when I do basically the same thing afterwards (read in the page each result points to), the output is barely streamed at all, being redrawn every minute or so.

I'm using `file_get_contents($url)` to retrieve the content, and calling a function with an `echo` in it to print what has been loaded so far. Is this streaming print behaviour a feature of the browser and independent of what I write in PHP? If not, how can it be controlled better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest fix is to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).  The basic idea is to call `ob_start()` at the beginning of your script and then call `ob_end_flush()` when you want the pages content to be sent to the client.  Doing this will save all of your output until you want your program to send it.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly seems to be what I was looking for, but it still doesn't quite work as expected. I've read through the documentation and comments, flushed everything a hundred times at the start, and have an ob_flush() after every interesting print, but it still prints at strange intervals (every 13 results, when there's 10 per page).

Could be an issue with the chunk size? I set it to 3 bytes in php.ini, so that should have fixed it. Maybe I should restart the server...

Comment: Could there be a problem with your algorithm? Otherwise, I'm not sure why it would be printing every 13 results.  Maybe there's some weird thing going on with your webserver?

Comment: Ah, got it. I had to call `ob_flush();` and then `flush();` as well (in that order, I believe), not just one or the other, and I had to do that each time. Confusing stuff. Works perfectly now though, thanks!